# Android Eclipse 'Source not found' at execute

Tags: java, android, eclipse, post, execute

I've a problem in Eclipse while coding an Android App..

If I'm in debug mode and go line-by-line through my code I get an error with the Message "Source not found".

Here is my Code:

```
public boolean checkVersion(){
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+this.ip+"/fastorder/android/checkDatabaseVersion.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
    try{
        String db_vers = String.valueOf(DATABASE_VERSION);
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar, 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("version", db_vers));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];


        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Execute HTTP Post Request
        //response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("Response: " + response); 

        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){


            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Speisekarte aktualisieren?");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Wollen Sie jetzt die aktuelle Version der Speisekarte downloaden?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            loadUpdate();
                        }
                      })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();


        }
        else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){

        }

    }catch(ClientProtocolException e){
        Log.e("FastOrder", "Exception : " + e);
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("FastOrder", "Exception : " + e);
    }

    return true;
}
```

the error apears in: `String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);` line...

Anyone has an answer? I try to fix this since days...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the source code for the method you are trying to access cannot be found.

Try pressing [F6] at the line where you get the error.

Comment: Uh? I press F6 when I go line-by-line through the code, isn't it? :D

Comment: Sorry. I thought you used F5 to step into. I'll try to get a solution

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Sry for bad english... i come from Germany :D

Comment: Don't worry man!. I'm from Colombia and sometimes my english is not good neither. Question: Do you have all dependencies for the api? httpcore.jar and commons-logging.jar?

Comment: Well, if you are using httpclient.jar you need those dependencies too.

Comment: No i don't have this... where can i get this from?

Comment: httpclient and httpcore: https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi
commons loggin: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Let me know if your issue is resolved

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use this classes, but how should I "install" it, only copy in lib folder? I'm new in Java and Eclipse... (I've download the httpclient.jar direct from developers.google.com)

Comment: select your project -> right click for menu -> properties -> java biuld path -> add external jars

Comment: okay.. I'm in case the stupist developer ever... I've add the zips, I've downloaded... this doesn't work... should I unzip it and add some .jars from the lib folder? I don't have an idea, sorry... :(

Comment: Ok. Don´t worry. If you downloaded httpclient file from https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi in zip format, you need to unzip the file and look for a lib folder in the unzipped file, then add all the .jar files located there to your eclipse project. Here's a how-to link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S56eQ9qZ820

Comment: Tank you! I've done this, but it doesn't work... the funny thing is, I do a login, with the same code and in the same package and there it goes well........

Comment: Have you an idea to fix this? :)